# How to open gallery and select image from gallery in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

I am working on a feature for an application such that whenever a user clicks the "browse" button the gallery will be explored and the user can select any desired image to save to database (image upload).
Kindly suggest me a solution. I'm using codename one plugin.

```
IDE : Netbeans    
OS : Device,Emulator
Platform : Android
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us some of the relevant portions of your code so we can help you figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
Display.getInstance().openImageGallery(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
         //...
     }
});
```

Comment: Please help our users by providing more details along with your answer. Perhaps elaborating on why this code works and why it should be used.

Comment: See the answer by submitter "This code is to save the image,but I'm stuck at how to open the gallery of device to get image....".

Comment: I don't know if I should open another question, but does this method support multiple image selection?

Answer (score 2):

i think you dont need it anymore, but there are still other people =)

```
Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                if (ev != null && ev.getSource() != null) {
                    String filePath = (String) ev.getSource();
                    int fileNameIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
                    String fileName = filePath.substring(fileNameIndex);

                    Image img = null;
                    try {
                        img = Image.createImage(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(filePath));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    MultiList photoList = findPhotoList();
                    Hashtable tableItem = new Hashtable();
                    tableItem.put("icon", img.scaled(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight() / 10, -1));
                    tableItem.put("emblem", fileName);
                    photoList.getModel().addItem(tableItem);
                    // Do something, add to List
                }
            }
        }, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
```

I created an extra Form, which contains a MultiList where i can put in Images with a Button.